# How to set the tolerance in Gradient descent?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent, batch-normalization, tolerance-interval

I understand that one solution of setting the number of iterations, is to set it to a large number and then interrupt it when the gradient vector becomes tiny, so tiny that it is smaller than *a tolerance value*

Now my question is how do you determine such value?

References:
O'Reilly Hands-On Machine Learning Book Page 119